# Which sentence is correct for passing of time?

Tags: time

Which sentence is correct for passing of time? "Whatever the time passes", "Whatever the time it passes over" or "Whatever the time goes on".
I need it for my scientific paper. My complete sentence is: "As it is evident, whatever the time passes, the convergence rate difference of the algorithms becomes more apparent."

Comment: That sentence is all kinds of wrong; it needs completely rewriting. We are not a proofreading service, we only answer *specific* questions. This is not specific enough.

Comment: Of the three, I prefer the first without the article: *whatever time passes*. But I don't think any of them fit particularly well in your sample sentence. If you're trying to say that you have some asymptotic behaviour, you may wish to reword your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, what you want to say is:

"*As evident*, the convergence rate difference of the algorithms becomes more apparent ***over time***."

Answer (score 0):

Which sentence is correct for "the" passing of time? 
None of the expressions listed could be considered correct unless it was in the context of poetry.

Comment: So, what is the correct sentence for scientific paper?